# DRY LINQ Predicate Filters for Multiple Tables

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, predicate

Suppose I have two tables, TableA and TableB. Each record in A has one or more related records in B. Say I want a reusable filter using predicates. I might do something like this (Linq-to-SQL by the way):

```
private Expression<Func<ARecord, bool>> FilterPredicate()
{
    return x => x.Name == "Test";
}

private IQueryable<ARecord> GetRecords()
{
    return DataContext.TableA.Where(FilterPredicate());
}
```

That works fine, but say I wanted to search TableB, but use the same "filter" on the foreign key. I want to accomplish the query below without having to rewrite FilterPredicate for how it relates to TableB.

```
var query = from b in DataContext.B
            where b.A.Name == "Test"
            select b;
```

I'm just wondering if there are any best practices for creating reusable "where" clauses that would help across multiple tables.

Edit - To clarify, I'm not looking for a way to apply the predicate to ARecord and BRecord types. I'm looking for a way (any way, not necessarily along the lines I was already thinking of) to prevent needing this predicate as well:

```
private Expression<Func<BRecord, bool>> FilterPredicate2()
{
    return x => x.A.Name == "Test";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess thinking more about it, it is somewhat of a stupid question. I was hoping to be able to use the cleaner query:

```
var query = from b in DataContext.B 
            select b;
```

And apply this to it:

```
x => x.A.Name == "Test"
```

Without having to have the duplicate this predicate that I use when starting the query on
the A table:

```
x => x.Name == "Test"
```

So I suppose the solution is to "reverse" the query by starting on the A table, like so:

```
var query = from a in DataContext.A
            join b in B on a equals b.A
            select b;

query = query.Where(FilterPredicate());
```

I was thinking it may rewrite the queries inefficiently, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by defining an interface over A and B.

```
public interface IHasName // contrived, I know
{
    string Name {get;}
}
```

LINQ-To-SQL classes are partial, so in your part of the partial class definition, you can add the interface like so:

```
public partial class A : IHasName {}
public partial class B : IHasName {}
```

As you see, no implementation should be needed since the Name property is implemented in the Linq-To-Sql generated part.

Now constrain your predicate to types implementing the IHasName interface, and you're all set:

```
private Expression<Func<T, bool>> FilterPredicate(string name) where T : IHasName
{
    return x => x.Name == name;
}
```

you should now even be able to define an extension method on IQueryable like so:

```
public static T GetByName<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, 
                             string name) where T : IHasName
{
    return queryable.Where(FilterPredicate(name)).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Small caveat: of course, the property in the interface ('Name') must exactly match the property name in the implementing classes. Suppose you have a class C with property 'MyName'. You might be tempted to implement the IHasName interface like so:

```
public partial class C : IHasName
{
    public string Name {return MyName;} 
}
```

This will of course not work, as the Linq-To-Sql expression parser will use 'Name' instead of the actual property 'MyName', so it won't be able to map this expression to valid SQL.

Comment: "This will of course not work, as the Linq-To-Sql expression parser will use 'Name' instead of the actual property 'MyName', so it won't be able to map this expression to valid SQL."

Actually, there is a way around this - it's kinda painful, but it works - 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/5691e0ad-ad67-47ea-ae2c-9432e4e4bd46

Comment: Please see my edit. I'm looking to filter on the foreign key, not apply the same predicate to A and B types.

Comment: This just helped me tremendously. I was hung up on trying to use the interface directly as a parameter in the predicate. Thank you.